# Cyrillic value insert error in SqlParameter on mono

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, mono, cyrillic

Next code snippet throws exception if I use as value in @Name string with cyrillic characters. If I use latin chars it works fine. On Windows host with .Net 4.0 works fine. But on Ubuntu 14.04 with last mono it has error. SQL server MS SQL 2014.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("INSERT INTO [MyTable]([Name],[ID]) ");
            sb.AppendLine("VALUES(");
            sb.Append("@Name, ");
            sb.Append("@ID)");
            SqlConnection sqlConnection =
                new SqlConnection(connStr);
            try
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), sqlConnection);

                SqlParameter sqlParameter = null;

                var msg = "Имя";
                sqlParameter = new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 0, "Name");
                sqlParameter.Value = msg;
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(sqlParameter);

                sqlParameter = new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.BigInt, 0, "ID");
                sqlParameter.Value = 39;
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(sqlParameter);

                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var a = 0;
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlConnection.Close();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
sqlParameter = new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, "Name");
```

instead of

```
sqlParameter = new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 0, "Name");
```